# Returning BSTR from OLE to Inno Setup

Tags: com, inno-setup, pascalscript

In my setup, created with Inno Setup 5.x I'm using code to perform HTTP request.

This is done by [`WinHttpRequest` COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winhttp/winhttprequest).

While it's fairly easy to pass string arguments to functions, I'm having trouble receiving them.

For example function `GetResponseHeader`

```c
HRESULT GetResponseHeader(
  [in]          BSTR Header,
  [out, retval] BSTR *Value
);
```

takes one IN argument and one OUT argument.

Passing empty string to `Value` results in `Invalid Variant Operation` being thrown.

What is the correct type for `[out, retval] BSTR *Value` on the Pascal side? How can I convert it to string? Should I manually release it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually that kind of method signature is converted to a function. Effectively, the method has this signature:

```pascal
function GetResponseHeader(Header: string): string;
```

So you can do:

```pascal
var
  WinHttpReq: Variant;
  ContentType: string;
begin
  WinHttpReq := CreateOleObject('WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1');
  WinHttpReq.Open('GET', 'https://www.example.com/', False);
  WinHttpReq.Send();
  ContentType := WinHttpReq.GetResponseHeader('Content-Type');
  Log(ContentType);
end;
```

Comment: In the end I found following sentence in the docs: `Be aware that automation clients, such as script, get the header data as the return value of the function call, not through a function parameter.`, but didn't want to post the answer before testing.

By the way, if you are the author of WinSCP, I feel honored.